# [Zend Framework 1]Send mail using gmail

Tags: php, linux, zend-framework

That is my code:

```
$config = array(
'ssl' => 'tls',
'port' => 587,
'auth' => 'login',
'username' => 'test@gmail.com',
'password' => 'test');

$mail = new Zend_Mail('UTF-8');
$transport = new Zend_Mail_Transport_Smtp('smtp.gmail.com', $config);

$mail->setBodyHtml('test');
$mail->setFrom('test@gmail.com', 'thrth');
$mail->addTo('test@mail.com', 'thr');
$mail->setSubject('test');
$mail->send($transport);
```

But have one error message:

> Could not open socket

I use CentOS 6.5 x86_x64 minimal with Oracle VM VirtualBox.

Comment: A side note: you better use a proper MTA like postfix, since they can reschedule sending in case if google was not available or had some problems.

Comment: This looks like a firewall issue

Answer (score -1):

Can you try changing the port to 465?